# Questions about using a .bat file

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

(using WinXP)

I've not written a batch file before. I want to create a shortcut for using virtuelenv. I normally have to open a shell, type `C:\some-path-to-my-env\Script\activate.bat`. Then I have a shell with the correct environment. I want to make a batch file that when clicked, opens a shell and does all that for me, so that I can have a usable shell with the env pre-loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as a shortcut to `cmd.exe /K "C:\some-path-to-my-env\Script\activate.bat"`
where `cmd.exe` opens a shell instance, `/K` instructs it to remain open after the command finishes, and the command itself is written in the `" "`'s after that.

Comment: thanks! BTW, how can I do multiple things like that (e.g. run the .bat file, and then cd into another directory)?

Comment: You can do this with a separate batch file in which the commands are, just put them in there as you would type them to the shell, or simply with one long combined command in the `" "` part where the individual commands are separated with `&`.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to run another batch file in a batch file, and then run more commands? If I put `cd some-dir`, new line, `some.bat`, new line, `cd some-other-dir`, it doesn't run anything past the first bat file.

Comment: try `call some.bat` .. this was some trial and error for me too